# How to display all iterations at once with JSTL in a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a a JSP page that goes through a list of items and adds to different counters based on a parameter of the items.

```
<c:forEach items="${studentSkills}" var="skill">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body-center">
                <c:set var="cicount" value="0" />
                <c:set var="pscount" value="0" />
                <c:set var="prcount" value="0" />
                <c:set var="jrcount" value="0" />
                <c:if test="${skill.category eq 'Community Involvement'}">
                    <p>
                        <c:set var="cicount" value="${cicount + 1}" />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${skill.category eq 'Personal Skill'}">
                    <p>
                        <c:set var="pscount" value="${pscount + 1}" />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${skill.category eq 'Physical Recreation'}">
                    <p>
                        <c:set var="prcount" value="${prcount + 1}" />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${skill.category eq 'Journey/Research'}">
                    <p>
                        <c:set var="jrcount" value="${jrcount + 1}" />
                </c:if>
                <p>Number of Students involved in -</p>
                <p>Community Involvement: ${cicount}</p>
                <p>Physical Recreation: ${prcount}</p>
                <p>Personal Skill: ${pscount}</p>
                <p>Journey/Research: ${jrcount}</p>
                <div id="mainwrap"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
```

This iterates through the List and assigns the value to the correct count. My problem is since its a ForEach loop it displays the data in its own separate part each time. i.e. its printing out this

```
                <p>Number of Students involved in -</p>
                <p>Community Involvement: ${cicount}</p>
                <p>Physical Recreation: ${prcount}</p>
                <p>Personal Skill: ${pscount}</p>
                <p>Journey/Research: ${jrcount}</p>
                <div id="mainwrap"></div>
```

every time there is an item in the list. 
I tried putting this bit outside the ForEach but then I get another problem where only 1 item is ever displayed. 
Is there a way I can keep it inside the loop but only have it displaying after all the counters are done?

This is the function which creates the new list and populates it

```
    User currentUser = userService.findByUsername(p.getName());
    List<User> students = currentUser.getStudents();
    List<Skill> studentSkills = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        String name = students.get(i).getUsername();
        User astudent = userService.findByUsername(name);
        studentSkills = astudent.getSkills();
    }

    //making sure the List is being populated
    for (Skill studentSkill : studentSkills ) {
        System.out.println(studentSkill.getSkillName());
        System.out.println(studentSkill.getCategory());
    }

    model.addAttribute("studentSkills", studentSkills);
    model.addAttribute("currentUser", currentUser);
    model.addAttribute("students", students);
```

Comment: You tried putting the increments outside the loop but it didn't work. Please show that code; your misunderstanding will probably be evident there.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Below Code :

```
<c:set var="cicount" value="0" />
<c:set var="pscount" value="0" />
<c:set var="prcount" value="0" />
<c:set var="jrcount" value="0" />
<c:forEach items="${studentSkills}" var="skill">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body-center">

            <c:if test="${skill.category eq 'Community Involvement'}">
                <p>
                    <c:set var="cicount" value="${cicount + 1}" />
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${skill.category eq 'Personal Skill'}">
                <p>
                    <c:set var="pscount" value="${pscount + 1}" />
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${skill.category eq 'Physical Recreation'}">
                <p>
                    <c:set var="prcount" value="${prcount + 1}" />
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${skill.category eq 'Journey/Research'}">
                <p>
                    <c:set var="jrcount" value="${jrcount + 1}" />
            </c:if>

        </div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
<p>Number of Students involved in -</p>
<p>Community Involvement: ${cicount}</p>
<p>Physical Recreation: ${prcount}</p>
<p>Personal Skill: ${pscount}</p>
<p>Journey/Research: ${jrcount}</p>
<div id="mainwrap"></div>
```